# Mock with Rhino mock -MVVM

Tags: unit-testing, .net-4.0, mocking, rhino-mocks

I am using Rhino mock for mocking in my test methods. Could someone please see the TODO part in the test method and help me to mock it?

This is my service interface:

```
public  interface ICustomersServiceAgent
{
    void GetCustomers(EventHandler<GetCustomersCompletedEventArgs> callback);
    void SaveCustomer(POC.Model.Customer cust, EventHandler<SaveCustomerCompletedEventArgs> callback);
}
```

This is my ViewModel

```
public class CustomerVM : ViewModelBase
{
    private Model.Customer _curentCustomer;
    private RelayCommand _saveCommand;
    private ICustomersServiceAgent ServiceAgent { get; set; }
    private bool isSaved;
    private RelayCommand _calculateAgeCommand;
    private Decimal age;
    private DateTime dateOfBirth;

    public CustomerVM(ICustomersServiceAgent serviceAgent)
    {
        if (serviceAgent == null)
        {
            ServiceAgent = ServiceManager.GetCustomerServiceManagement();
        }
        else
        {
            ServiceAgent =serviceAgent;
        }
        WireCommands();
    }

    // if curent object is null then it should be intialize
    public Model.Customer CurentCustomer
    {
        get { return _curentCustomer ?? (_curentCustomer = new Model.Customer()); }
        set
        {
            if (_curentCustomer != value)
            {
                _curentCustomer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurentCustomer");
            }
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand CalculateAgeCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private void WireCommands()
    {
        SaveCustomerCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveCustomer);
        SaveCustomerCommand.IsEnabled = true;
        CalculateAgeCommand = new RelayCommand(CalculateAge);
    }

    private void SaveCustomer()
    {
        var cus = CurentCustomer;
        ServiceAgent.SaveCustomer(cus, (s, e) =>
        {
            IsSaved = e.Result;
        });
    }

    private void CalculateAge()
    {
        Age = DateTime.Now.Year - DateOfBirth.Year;        
    }

    public RelayCommand SaveCustomerCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public bool IsSaved
    {
        get { return isSaved; }
        set
        {
            isSaved = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSaved");
        }
    }

    public decimal Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { 
            age = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Age");
        }
    }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth
    {
        get { return dateOfBirth; }
        set { 
            dateOfBirth = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DateOfBirth");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to test the `SaveCustomerCommand` in ViewModel above. 
So In the my test method, I want to mock the `void SaveCustomer(POC.Model.Customer cust, EventHandler<SaveCustomerCompletedEventArgs> callback)` method in the `ICustomersServiceAgent`   interface.

This is my test method, see the ToDo part

```
[TestMethod]
public void SaveCustomerCommandTest()
{
    var customerServiceMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICustomersServiceAgent>();
    var customerVM = new POC.SilverlightClient.ViewModel.CustomerVM(customerServiceMock);

    //  TO do :  Code to mock SaveCustomer method ///////////////////////////////////

    var saveCustomerCommand = customerVM.SaveCustomerCommand;
    saveCustomerCommand.Execute(null);

    Assert.IsTrue(customerVM.IsSaved);
}
```

Could someone please explain how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need to mock SaveCustomer. All the private SaveCustomer method does is invoke the `ServiceAgent` service which you already are mocking. I assume the RelayCommand class invokes the delegate you're sending in the constructor parameter which is the call to SaveCustomer. Have you tried running the unit test in your question as-is?

Comment: Yes.But it does not work ,Because the SaveCustomer Method does not mock . It only mock ICustomersServiceAgent.So that I want to mock 
SaveCustomer method .Unfortunately I could not do it ..

Comment: If you edit your question to describe how the unit test "does not work", then people will have more information on what your are trying to do and may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
customerServiceMock.Stub(sa => sa.SaveCustomer(Arg<POC.Model.Customer>.Is.Anything, Arg<EventHandler<SaveCustomerCompletedEventArgs>>.Is.Anything)).WhenCalled(invocation =>
        {
            ((EventHandler<SaveCustomerCompletedEventArgs>)invocation.Arguments[1])(
customerServiceMock, 
new SaveCustomerCompletedEventArgs { Result = true });
        });
```